# Galois group of a quartic

Tags: polynomials

Given the quartic
$$x^4−2 x^3+(^2−^2) x^2+2^2  x−^2 ^2=0$$
for integers $,$ and $$ where $^2=^2+^2$.

Can anybody prove that the Galois group cannot be $\mathbb{Z}_4$ when $a \neq b$? I have an elementary proof when $b = a$.

Comment: Looking at the resolvent cubic may help.

Comment: Please use LaTeX/MathJax formatting.

Comment: Have a look at the notes by K. Conrad on Galois groups of quartics.

Comment: I know a lot about Galois theory for quartics. But, this seems to a tricky one.

Comment: Where did this quartic come from?

Comment: This quartic comes from the s-ocalled non-square ladder box problem known from recreational mathematics.

Comment: Even Newton, Descartes and Lagrange studied this quartic (at least for the b = a case)!

Comment: You mean the quartic in the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_ladders_problem ?

Comment: No, this is the so-called crossed ladder problem. See https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1987.11977313 from MM 1987. I can send you the paper I wrote about the Galois group for the square ladder box problem (b= a  case).

Comment: For references to the two types of ladder problems, see CMJ (The College Mathematics Journal) 2008, page 161.